# How to handle a copy of div to another div with data-id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div having element that repeats itself 4 times with a different data-id
I want to create a copy of div to another div,
By class and data-id of the same element I clicked on.

The copy is moved to a pop-up

What I have been able to reach so far is this:

```
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$ (document) .ready (function () {
     $ (". woobt-product-together"). on ("click", function () {
         var dataId = $ (this) .attr ("data-id");
     $ (document) .ready (function () {
   $ ("# div2"). html ($ (". woobt-product-together"). html ());
     });
});

});
```

What is happening right now is that only the first class on the list is copied, to all the different pop-ups

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the first class on the list is copied"? Where does this code copy any classes?

Comment: What does that mean?
I have a div whose class is the same, and each has a different data-id